# how to specify when to re-trigger hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, rtk-query

I'm trying to update my react tool knowledge, adding RTK

Was going over the overview for `RTK Query` https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview

and ended up with somwthing like this:

```
export const todoApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'todoApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getAllTodos: builder.query<Task[], string>({
      query: () => `todos`,
    }),
  }),
})

// Export hooks for usage in functional components, which are
// auto-generated based on the defined endpoints
export const { useGetAllTodosQuery } = todoApi
```

in the slice:

```
export const todoSlice = createSlice({
  name: "todo",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addTask: //[...],
    toggleTask: // [...],
    fillTodos: (state, action: PayloadAction<Task[]>) => {
      // debugger;
      state.todos = action.payload
    }
  }
});
```

so, finally in the component, I'm trying to pull from the API:

```
export function Todo() {

  const todos = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.todo.todos);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  
    const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetAllTodosQuery("")
    if (data) {
      dispatch(fillTodos(data));
    }
```

This would roughly work, updating the store with the pulled `todos`, but it would trigger the `useGetAllTodosQuery` every time the component re-renders (even several times while mounting or when updating the store with an unrelated action -like to complete a task-). Kinda was looking for a similar to `useEffect` param  to specify when to trigger the effect again.
I guess I'm missing some basics.

Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It actually does not refetch multiple times. It fetches once.

And then data is in the cache and it does not make a request until you manually call `.refetch` on the result, or use the automatic refetching feature with providesTags/invalidatesTags.

If you want to get deeper into RTK Query, follow [chapter 7 and 8 of the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-7-rtk-query-basics)

PS: you should not really copy that data out of RTK Query into your own slices if you can avoid it. Just call the `use...Query` hook with the same argument everywhere you need that data.